# Creating a matrix with random generated variables in R

Tags: r, matrix

I want to create a matrix with 100 rows and 5 columns. Values for the first column are 1 or 2. Values for the second column are integers from 1 to 5. Values for the third column are integers from 10 to 50. Values for the fourth column are integers from 1 to 3. And values for the fifth column are integers from 1 to 5. How do randomly assign these generated values for each row in this matrix? Thanks,

Comment: It is not clear what you wanted.  Do you want to randomize the values in each column or does the row as a whole would go together?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
mat <- as.matrix(data.frame(V1 = sample(1:2,   100, replace = TRUE),
                 V2 = sample(1:5,   100, replace = TRUE),
                 V3 = sample(10:50, 100, replace = TRUE),
                 V4 = sample(1:3,   100, replace = TRUE),
                 V5 = sample(1:5,   100, replace = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Yes, Mist, this is exactly what I needed. Cheers,